# duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.syscolpars'

Tags: ssms, collation

```
ALTER DATABASE testDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 

GO 

ALTER DATABASE testDatabase COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI; 

GO 

ALTER DATABASE testDatabase SET MULTI_USER; 

GO
```

Error :

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.syscolpars' and the index name 'nc'. The duplicate key value is (397960494, Categorie, 0).
> Msg 5072, Level 16, State 1, Line 5

I'm trying to alter the database collation, and i'm getting this error, i don't understand why, tried to select the dbo.syscolpars, but i'm unable to/don't know how, please enlighten me !!

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.